# CUDA 9.0 with MSVC 15.4 (2017) as host - incompatibility issues

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, visual-studio-2017, nvcc

Why does this command line work on VS2015:

```
"C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/bin/nvcc.exe" -M -D__CUDACC__ D:/gPMCbct/RTK/code/rtkCudaCropImageFilter.cu -o D:/gPMCbct/RTK-build/code/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir//cuda_compile_1_generated_rtkCudaCropImageFilter.cu.obj.NVCC-depend -ccbin "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin" -m64 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DITK_IO_FACTORY_REGISTER_MANAGER -Xcompiler ,\"/DWIN32\",\"/D_WINDOWS\",\"/W3\",\"/GR\",\"/EHsc\",\"/std:c++14\",\"/arch:AVX2\",\"/favor:INTEL64\",\"/openmp\",\"/bigobj\",\"/MDd\",\"/Zi\",\"/Ob0\",\"/Od\",\"/RTC1\" -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=compute_35 -DNVCC -ID:/gPMCbct/RTK "-IC:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/include" -ID:/gPMCbct/ITKv4/Modules/Core/Common/include -ID:/gPMCbct/ITKv4-build/Modules/Core/Common -ID:/gPMCbct/RTK-build
```

When basically the same command line fails in VS2017:

```
"C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/bin/nvcc.exe" -M -D__CUDACC__ D:/gPMCbct/RTK/code/rtkCudaCropImageFilter.cu -o D:/gPMCbct/RTK-build/code/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile_1.dir//cuda_compile_1_generated_rtkCudaCropImageFilter.cu.obj.NVCC-depend -ccbin "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/bin" -m64 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DITK_IO_FACTORY_REGISTER_MANAGER -Xcompiler ,\"/DWIN32\",\"/D_WINDOWS\",\"/W3\",\"/GR\",\"/EHsc\",\"/std:c++14\",\"/arch:AVX2\",\"/favor:INTEL64\",\"/openmp\",\"/bigobj\",\"/MDd\",\"/Zi\",\"/Ob0\",\"/Od\",\"/RTC1\" -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=compute_35 -DNVCC -ID:/gPMCbct/RTK "-IC:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/include" -ID:/gPMCbct/ITKv4/Modules/Core/Common/include -ID:/gPMCbct/ITKv4-build/Modules/Core/Common -ID:/gPMCbct/RTK-build
```

The only difference is the path to the host compiler, i.e. the "-ccbin" argument.

`--verbose` prints the output of vcvars64.bat and every environment path, then exits with `%error_level% = 1`.

Both commands are generated with CMake.

An exit code of 1 is not really helpful for anything other than knowing that *something* went wrong.
How do I get more information on why the command fails?

I have found similar problems on threads and mailing lists, but either, the real problem was not resolved or the solution did not work here (some windows path problems, some include/linking problems and some source code problems)

The same problem also happens in another CMake generated project with completely different source code.

Answer (score 3):

The solution appears to be as simple as changing the `-ccbin` path for VS17 to the **filepath** of the correct `cl.exe`, in my example the correct path was:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe
```

The `-ccbin` argument is the same as the `CUDA_HOST_COMPILER` variable in CMake.